# Default select option value is undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a `select` with 2 options inside and my goal is to show/hide html elements depending on the option selected. There is no empty option, so there's always either "default" or "custom" selected.

For that I'm using jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.template-type').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'default') {
        $("#default_template").show();
        $("#custom_template").hide();
      } else {
        $("#default_template").hide();
        $("#custom_template").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

But when I reload the page, regardless of the option saved, both html elements are visible again and a console log of `this.options` tells me it's `undefined`, but the option selected after reload matched the option saved before.
Only when I pick other option again it works as intended.

This is the select, a Symfony `ChoiceType` field, just in case is needed:

```
    case 'email_category':
        $attrFields = array('class' => 'form-control template-type');
        $formFieldType = ChoiceType::class;
        $optionFields = array('choices'  => array('Default' => 'default', 'Custom' => 'custom'), 'choices_as_values' => true, 'label' => 'Type of template used:');
        break;
```

Comment: "a console log of this.options tells me it's undefined" is very suspect.  `this` is contextual, and if you are not within the context of the select, it will obviously be undefined.

Comment: what about `console.log($(this).val());` ?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are setting `selected` server side , you can trigger the change event after you declare the change handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.template-type').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'default') {
      $("#default_template").show();
      $("#custom_template").hide();
    } else {
      $("#default_template").hide();
      $("#custom_template").show();
    }
  // trigger the change on page load
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: That's it, all I needed was the change event. Thank you